# Does this problem requires Supervised Learning or Unsupervised Learning

Tags: neural-networks, boosting, feature-engineering, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I have 50 Features in a Dataset to predict 1 Variable "Units Sold". I am currently using XGBoost model (Supervised Learning) to train all these 50 Features and the accuracy of the model on the test dataset (after dividing the entire dataset in train/test ratio) is very good.

But in reality, I can ask for only 3 of the Features (out of 50) from the user. And based on these 3 inputs from the user, I need to Forecast the "Units Sold".

Ideally, if I use only these 3 features for training the model, the accuracy falls very low which is why I want to include all these 50 features while training.

**I am thinking that since number of features Available while doing the forecast are less than the ones used for Training, I should be using Unsupervised Learning or some other approach.
That is what I need the guidance on.**

The list for all the features would be very long but I will mention a few important ones:-

- **Week_End**
- **ArticleID**
- **Ads_Used** (this is a factor of 5 unique values and are used as
  one-hot-encoding)
- **Units_Lag** (Units sold in the previous Week. There are 4 Lags to cover
  whole month)
- **Units_Percentage_With_Ads** (which Ad sold how many Units that week)

etc.

From the user, I can input only the "**Week_End**", "**ArticleID**" and "**Ad_Type**".

Comment: Classical neural networks (no matter how deep) are part of supervised learning.

Comment: How do you know of the 50 features, if you in reality only get 3? Are the 50 from an artifical data set? 50 features for a simple sales modeling is a way too high complexity imho. And additionally you used Units_sold lag. lagged sales variables normally explain a sales model really good, if you are not interested in "how" where the contributions from other features, as long as you only want to forecast sales. What is the question here btw?

Comment: @PatrickBormann: You are absolutely right. These Lags and Percentages of sales are in fact made artificially while based on Time (weeks and months) and Sales. And they do indeed when give to the model for training form a very robust model.

The issue is, if I want to Forecast for the next year, I wouldn't have these variables: Lags and Percentages since they are related to current or historic sales.
The Question is: how to compensate for these Artificial Variables while doing prediction since a user, while selecting the combination of Ads and Articles and Future Time, wouldn't know these ?